# Android Studio Error When Generating Signed APK: Exception in plugin Android support

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to generate signed apk using Android Studio 3.2 Canary 13. I get this error window:
[image]

[image]

I tried Invalidate Caches/Restart, and nothing happened.

Comment: that is a reason why I don't use carnary builds. The only way to avoid this errors is to use stable builds.

Comment: It looks like that's what I'm going to do too.

Comment: I've reported the same issue here, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79230920 , no response yet.

Comment: Great, let us know

Comment: This issue has been fixed in Canary 14 :
[Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78889410)